# Is it possible to write a Telegram bot using pure Javascript?

Tags: telegram-bot

I would like to create a simple Telegram bot using JavaScript. But when I am trying to google it (since I'm not very good at working with APIs) I can find only solutions which are using Node.js.

So, that is the question. Is there any reasons why I can't use pure js for this purpose? If there aren't, are there any articles to read?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pure JS" has no mechanisms for input or output, so it can't make network requests. It depends on the host environment to provide such things.

Example host environments include webpages (running in web browsers), Node.js, and Adobe Photoshop.

Node.js is a common solution because it is designed to allow a wide range of software development to be done in JavaScript. This is why you see plenty of solutions using it.

(Web browsers, by contrast, are designed to let authors of webpages run programs on visitors' computers just because the visitor clicked a link to the webpage — as such there are major restrictions on what JavaScript programs in webpages are allowed to do. Likewise, Photoshop is designed to let people use JS to automate graphics manipulation, not perform general programming work.)